# Django rest framework + react native. Как проверить автора поста

Tags: django, reactjs, native

Есть api на django rest framework которое возвращает список постов. Редактировать пост может только автор поста. С api проблем нет. Тестировал через postman. В react native по нажатию на пост перехожу на скрин детальной информации. На этом скрине если пост мой должна быть кнопка "редактировать" если не мой то кнопки быть не должно. Вопрос как проверить чей пост?